# Movilizer scanner 1D barcode

Tags: android, barcode, mel, movilizer

I have a problem with scanning 1D barcode with movilizer app.

It works perfectly when I scan the code for the first time, but with every next try, it doesn't work at All, it's like the screen does not recognize the image as barcode, or the image is blurry.

Only way to scan barcode once again is to restart the app, and go through the whole process again.

I tried it with multiple devices, such as xiaomi redmi note 5, redmi note 8 pro, and realme 7. It Worked only on note 8. Movilizer app and camera settings were same on each device, aswell as participant ID.

I Also tried to have native camera app started on background, but it did not work.

I'm trying to figure this out for almost two weeks and found nothing...

Code for the movelet is exactly as the 1D capture barcode example in the reference guide:

```
<!-- CAPTURE BARCODE 1D -->
<question key="#1" type="22" title="My Screen">
     
    <!-- ANSWER -->
    <answer key="#1_1" attributeType="0" nextQuestionKey="END">
         
        <text>My Barcode</text>
         
    </answer>
     
    <text>Hello World</text>
     
</question>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, is this the only code that you have in your movelet? I copied and create a movelet from my side and it works properly on my client (Mi 9T). And what do you mean with "the image is blurry"? Do you see it blurry when open the camera?

Comment: yes, this is the only code in my movelet. My "blurry" image looks like camera couldn't be focused, but when I open classic camera app, it works without any problems.

Comment: And can you tell me what client version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.6.27